# Under what circumstances does the page cache in SQLite get cleared?

Tags: ios, sqlite, caching

I use sqlite in an iOS app.  Sometimes I replace a sqlite file at runtime and close and reopen my connections to it. But sqlite often seems to return query results from the old file when connected to the new file. My guess so far is that it's somehow keeping and using the page cache from the old file.

So my question is this: under what circumstances does SQLite's page cache get dropped?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I was walking through all my connections and closing and reopening each. When I simply closed them all (and let them get reopened later on demand as needed), the cache appeared to get cleared. My guess is that the cache is per-file and not per-connection, and it gets reset when all the connections to the file are closed. This can be tricky to achieve in a multithreaded environment.